# Derivative of remainder function.

Tags: derivatives

I cannot find a derivative of **remainder** function (i.e. derivative of `a(x) mod b(x)` with respect to `x`, and `x` is a real number and `a()`, `b()` is also real-valued functions) in tables of derivatives. Without the loss of generality, we may assume (and it desired at all), that continuous approximation is acceptable.

I note, that `(a(x) mod const)' ~ a'(x)`, `(c(x) mod c(x))' = 0`, but still I can't conclude form of desired right hand side `(a(x) mod b(x))' -> ?` function from these borderline cases (maybe dimensional method or method of indefinite coefficients in some form is applicable, but I have not an intuitions of how).

What is the generalized (in sense of continuity) form of **remainder** derivative?

I mean a [**remainder** function](http://www.website.masmforum.com/tutorials/fptute/fpuchap12.htm#fprem) as presented on *x86/x86-64* architectures (**FPREM** and **FPREM1**).

Comment: For even mildly general $a(x)$, $b(x)$ there seems to be no natural definition of remainder function.

Comment: @AndréNicolas It's incredible. I intuitively feel that the solution is expressed in terms of elementary functions or even of couple of multiplications, additions, subtractions and divisions of operands and its first derivatives.

Comment: @MPW I think there are at least two cases: when `lhs < rhs` and vice-versa.

Comment: There is a standard definition of the remainder when $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are polynomials. So any conjectured answer should probably give the "right thing" for polynomials.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Interesting note. I'll try to find the solution for polinomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you defining "$a(x) \mod b(x)$"? Is it something like $a(x) - b(x)[a(x)/b(x)]$ (perhaps assuming $a,b>0$)? If so, and if $a,b$ are continuous, then I would think it is $a'(x)$ (where it exists) since $[\cdot]$ is mostly piecewise constant, right? Of course, there will be holes in the domain of this derivative where jumps occur in the function ($a \mod b$) being differentiated.

**EDIT:** Oh, I see I drew the wrong conclusion. Since $[\cdot]$ is mostly constant, this means that the derivative will be $a'(x) - b'(x)[a(x)/b(x)]$ where it exists. Better?

Comment: If $[\cdot]$ is constant regardless of constancy of an argument, than derivative is $a'(x) - [a(x)/b(x)] \cdot b'(x)$ except the points, where $a(x) = n \cdot b(x)$ for some natural $n$. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I just realized that and have already edited my answer. You are correct.

Comment: $a'(x)$ is an answer only when $a(x) < b(x)$

Comment: @Dukales: The derivative could still exist where $a=n\cdot b$, as long as $[a/b]$ doesn't jump there.

Comment: Hmm... $[a / b]$ difenitely have steps when dividend growth and passes the points of multiplicity with respect to divisor. In such points the quotient have integer values.